# SQL BigQuery Rows to column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unpivot

This is a sample of my data

[image]

I am trying to get :

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpivot in BigQuery using `unnest()` and arrays:

```
select t.holiday, t.segment, el.dte, el.booking
from t cross join
     unnest(array[struct('1/1/2020' as dte, "1/1/2020" as booking),
                  struct('1/2/2020' as dte, "1/2/2020" as booking),
                  . . .
                 ]
            ) el;
```

Comment: Although this is totally correct, I would like to note that BigQuery doesn't allow column names starting with numbers. Specifically, from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names): *"A column name must contain only letters (a-z, A-Z), numbers (0-9), or underscores (_), and it must start with a letter or underscore."*.